# featured image and title are not added to shared post on facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, yoast

I'm using **[Social Warfare](https://warfareplugins.com/)** for sharing and **[Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/)** with **WordPress 5.4.1**

I fixed the yoast information asking for meta title, description and image.
but when I share a post on facebook, my share does not contain any information.

OnClick on the facebook post, the link is good.

How can I add the good title, description and image to my facebook post?

Comment: How can we help you without knowing what you are doing. You can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to debug your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the inspector of your browser (right click) and check the code in your html head element.

Are the meta tags you are needing set up correctly? For example:

```
<meta name="description" content="Correct meta description">
```

If the code of the head of your post is fine, there is a problem with facebook reading this information. It often is a problem of the cache if you have tried the link in facebook, but edited the meta information again after that. For me it helped a lot of times, if I used the facebook sharing debugger and pasted my link in. This way, you should get the current meta information of the post and facebook will notice it:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

If Facebook still don't get your meta data, you should maybe adjust your meta tags, if it is very important for you to post to facebook:

https://ogp.me/

This way, your tag should look like this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
```